# Vmware: accidentally restored the snapshot how to restore original state?

Tags: esxi, snapshot, vsphere

I had restored accidentally restored the vsphere snapshot how to recover to original state?

Comment: Restoring a snapshot deletes the current delta disks and branches new delta disks from the specified snapshot.  If you need to recover the old disk state, you will need to find a tool to recover deleted files from VMFS.

Answer (score 2):

> Vmware: accidentally restored the snapshot how to restore original
> state?

VMware snapshots are meant to be tested and then integrated.

Once integrated as you did, you either must:

(a) Restore the machine from a backup;  or,

(b) Back out changes you made.

There is not, in my experience with VMware, an UNDO function to back out combining (integrating) snapshots.